# How to solve a DNF-SAT problem with PySAT?

Tags: python, sat-solvers, pysat

is there any support for DNF formulas with PySAT? For example, can I call a SAT solver on a DNF formula using this module. In particular is there any way to turn a DNF into CNF using this python module?

I looked at the documentation but there seems to be no mention of DNF formulas at all.

Answer (score 1):

[Disjunctive Normal Form (DNF)](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DisjunctiveNormalForm.html) corresponds to the rows of a truth-table where the output value is `1` or `true`. Therefore, `DNF` already lists all solutions for the expression to be solved. No SAT solving is required in this case.

SAT solvers come into play for [Conjunctive Normal Form (CNF)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form). They are also used, if the expression(s) relate to circuits of logical gates.